# Forget an UNIX environment variables

Tags: unix, ubuntu, environment-variables

I remember there is an environment variable in UNIX that tells applications where to find the server with which it should communicate in order to display the output. Can anyone tell me what it its called?

Comment: you might talk about PATH

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are talking about the X server, it might be `$DISPLAY`, see https://askubuntu.com/questions/432255/what-is-display-environment-variable